# Double to String using Java standards

Tags: java

I have the below code:

```
  double cellValue = 78871234510124568.0;

  String cell = new BigDecimal(cellValue).toPlainString(); 
  String b = String.format("%.0f", cellValue);

  System.out.println("Double Value using Big Decimal " + cell);
  System.out.println("Double Value using String format " + b);
```

The double value which I set is not returned as output.

> Double Value using Big Decimal 78871234510124576
> Double Value using String format 78871234510124576

Is there a standard way to convert a `Double` to a `String` without explicit type casting with the range of value being `long` data type (max value) instead of `double`?

My intention of asking this question is because I am reading an Excel sheet using Apache POI with all cell types being general in the Excel sheet. I am using `getNumericCellValue()` to read the value of a cell which always returns a number in decimal format. For example 222 will be returned as 22.0. I want to remove the decimal and convert it to a string.

Comment: Just wondering: does the pattern "%f" actually work on a String as input? What is the intention by turning a number into a string; to then format that string as number?

Comment: For java, `78871234510124568.0` and `78871234510124576` are the same number, because a double is not large enough to store so many decimals so precisely

Comment: My Intention of asking this question is because am reading an excel sheet using apache POI ...with all cell type being general in th Excel..am using getNumericCellValue() to read the value of a cell..which always returns number in decimal format Example 222 will be returned as 22.0 ...I want to remove the decimal and convert it to a String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that many bits of precision (significant decimal places) you are trying to handle, you need to avoid using `Double`.

So, first you should check the cell content really has that many decimal places. (Depends on how the value has been entered.)

If yes, then you would need to get a string representation from POI and use this directly, or feed the String value to `BigDecimal` to get a numeric value.

If you can not arrange POI to return the high precision value as a String, you might not use POI successfully, as it is representing numeric values using `double` internally. Tus, relevant information is already lost when reading the data file.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, the root cause of your issue is when you get the `double` from POI:

```
Cell myCell = ... ;
double cellValue = myCell.getNumericCellValue();
```

There, `cellValue` would already have the same internal representation for both `78871234510124568.0` and `78871234510124576.0` (and at least all numbers inbetween):

```
System.err.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(78871234510124568.0));
System.err.println(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(78871234510124576.0));
```

Output:

```
4859809850462277474
4859809850462277474
```

This is simply a matter of how floating point values are stored in memory. There are just not enough bits available to distinguish between these numbers.
See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for more information.

If you need a higher accuracy, you must retrieve the value as a `String` and then use the `String` for further processing, like parsing it into a `BigDecimal`:

```
Cell myCell = ... ;
String cellValue = myCell.getStringCellValue();
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) df.parse(cellValue);
```

You need to consider the proper locale, so that the decimal point is treated correctly (`.` vs. `,`). `Locale.US` uses `.`.

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a large number to a `double` you will lose some information.  You can only put back that information if your either

- make assumptions about what the error is. e.g. rounding to 2 decimal places.
- you know what the error is.

One way this is done with doubles is to have two doubles. One with the main values and one with the error.

```
long l = 78871234510124568L;
double cellValue = l;
double err = l - (long) cellValue;

long original = (long) cellValue + (long) err;

System.out.println("cellValue="+cellValue+" err="+err+" original="+original);
```

prints

```
cellValue=7.8871234510124576E16 err=-8.0 original=78871234510124568
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
DecimalFormat amountFormatter = new DecimalFormat("############");
String s = amountFormatter.format(amount.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Out put will be 78871234510124576.00 But i want it to be 78871234510124568 is it because such a huge value will not be supported by Double??